# Remove sqlite database and replace with default from bundle

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite, replace

I used the Master-Detail-Application example at Xcode 4.3.3 to develope a data viewer. The app is downloading several files and append each file to a cell at the tableview. everything works fine. but if the user starts the download again, I need to remove all the previous data from the database and the tableview.
I ended up with the following steps:

1. remove the old store from coordinator
2. remove the old sqlite database file
3. copy the default ( empty ) sqlite db file from the bundle dir into the doc dir
4. update store coordinator
5. update tableview.

but now the problem is, that if I do so, the new data is not written into sqlite file. 
Please, can someone check my code. The following code is located at the MasterViewController.m ! I working on this since several days and I am totally stuck !!!

Thank you!

```objc
NSLog(@"Delete existing database file and copy default from bundle dir!");

NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSError *error = nil;

//get the documents directory:    

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// create database path documents dir

NSString *databasepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"Destination Database Path = %@", databasepath);

// create database path bundle dir

NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"Recource Database Path = %@", resourceDBFolderPath);

// remove old store from coordinator
error = nil;

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyDatabase" withExtension:@"momd"];
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL]];

NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

NSURL *storeURL = [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];    

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) 
    if (error != nil){

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }    


NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [[persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] objectAtIndex:0];
[persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:persistentStore error:&error];
if (error) 
    if (error != nil){
        NSLog(@"error removing persistent store %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

// Remove old database file

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyDatabase.sqlite"] error: &error];
if (error != nil){
    NSLog(@"delete Database status: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

// copy default empty database file into documents dir

[fileManager copyItemAtPath: resourceDBFolderPath toPath: databasepath           
                      error: &error];
if (error != nil){
    NSLog(@"copy default Database status: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} 


// then update storecoordinator

// add clean store file back by adding a new persistent store with the same store URL
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                              configuration: nil 
                                                        URL: storeURL 
                                                    options: nil 
                                                      error: &error]) {
    NSLog(@"failed to add db file, error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}


NSLog(@"Database replacement end!");
```

Comment: You have some bizarre blocks of code where you surround `NSLog()` statements simply with `{}`, but no if statements. I would guess that you're missing a `if (error)` in a couple places.  Not saying this is your problem, but it's confusing, and it might mess up your logging output.

Comment: This is just a transfer problem. It happened during copy. There are if statements. but this is not the reason, why it doesn't work !

Comment: If you read my comment, I acknowledged that this isn't the reason for the bug.  But, if you had cut and paste errors on those statements, maybe you have more?  It's also confusing for us trying to help you to read through code that has mistakes like that.  Help us to help you.

Comment: hi Nate, i corrected the code. Now it should be easy to read. I just can't figure out, why the steps above are successfully replacing the db file, but the new db file did not receive any data. Is the way  I am doing this right? Later at my code I am saving data to the sqlite DB. If I do this without replacing the DB file everything is correct, but I have the previous data and the new one. But if I add the code above the new database file stays empty.Is the way I am adding the new store coordinator correct?